# how to use ng2-translate preload translations to use in component class

Tags: ng2-translate

I am newbie to `angular2`, i able to translate using `ng2-translate` by using PIPE in template or html for example: {{ 'test' | translate}}
But any idea what if i want translate validation message or any string value inside any of component.ts class?
Anyone can help, it took me 3 days already